# ggplot2 segemt plot inside a loop - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a script which I wish it to print out the 5 x,y coordinates, to draw a segment line between a fix point (xCenterpoint, yCenterpoint) and another coordinates (Ax, Ay) and to plot another segment line between pairs of coordinates (Ax, Ay vs. Bx, By). Bx and By coordinates are the following coordinates pairs.

-While running the script in the printout I get NULL at the end of every line, why?
-Why the segment plots are not running inside the loop? 
-What is the problem with the colors and how can I fix it?

Thanks a lot

Script:

```
library(ggplot2)

xCoord <- c(0,2.5,5,7.5,10)
yCoord <- c(0,2.5,5,2.5,0)

xCenterpoint <- 5
yCenterpoint <- 0

df = data.frame(xCoord, yCoord  )

P1 <- ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = df$xCoord, y = df$yCoord))+ geom_point(aes(xCenterpoint, yCenterpoint),colour="red",size=4)

nElem <-nrow(df)-1

for(i in 1:nElem) 
{
  Ax <- df[i,1]
  Ay <- df[i,2]
  Bx <- df[i+1,1]
  By <- df[i+1,2]
  print(cat("Ax coord: ", Ax, "Ay coord: ", Ay, "Bx coord: ", Bx, "By coord: ", By)) #why NULL in the print?
  P1+ geom_segment(aes(x = xCenterpoint, y = yCenterpoint, xend = Ax, yend = Ay, colour = "green"), data = df)+
    geom_segment(aes(x = Ax, y = Ay, xend = Bx, yend = By, colour = "yellow"), data = df)
}
```

Comment: Just put `print` around your `P1 + ...` in the loop.

Comment: does not seems to work

Comment: The `print` statement does work for me. Also, don't use both `print` and `cat`. Just use one, e.g. `cat("Ax coord: ", Ax, "Ay coord: ", Ay, "Bx coord: ", Bx, "By coord: ", By, "\n")` works fine. Also perhaps add `scale_color_identity`. In the future, try to ask one simple question at a time, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 3 solved (comment above was just to solve that it prints plot in loop):

```
for(i in 1:nElem) {
  Ax <- df[i,1]
  Ay <- df[i,2]
  Bx <- df[i+1,1]
  By <- df[i+1,2]
  # remove print, add \n for linebreak, add maybe sep = "\t" for better formatting of output:
  cat("Ax coord: ", Ax, "Ay coord: ", Ay, "Bx coord: ", Bx, "By coord: ", By, "\n", sep = "\t")
  # wrap print around it and take color out of aes, since it is not mapped to data:
  print(P1 + geom_segment(aes(x = xCenterpoint, y = yCenterpoint, xend = Ax, yend = Ay), colour = "green", data = df)+
    geom_segment(aes(x = Ax, y = Ay, xend = Bx, yend = By), colour = "yellow", data = df))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The print statement works fine for me. The loop only shows the last segment plot, how can it also show on the same plot all the previous ones?

Comment: All the previous plots collected in one: put them all in a list and use something like `cowplot::plot_grid()` to print that list.